# Can't place endwhile in the loop properly in a shortcode

Tags: shortcode

I'm having trouble placing endwhile in the proper place in a shortcode I made to grab data from a custom post type.

I'm using ACF (advanced custom fields) for custom fields.

As of now, the code doesn't fully work and I suspect it has to do with no 'endwhile' , 'endif' , or  'wp_reset_query()' (though I'm new to php).

Here's the shortcode I have for this:

```
// Add Shortcode
function custom_shortcode() {

    // find todays date
    $date = date('Ymd');

    // args
    $args = array(
        'post_type'     => 'events',
        'meta_key'      => 'event_date',
        'meta_value'    => '$date'
    );


    // query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

            // The Loop
            if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

                $out .= '<ul>';
                while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                    $the_query->the_post();
                    $out .= "<div>";
                    $out .= get_field('event_name') . "<br>";
                $out .='<img class="myimage" style="max-width:180px;" src='. get_field('event_image') . ">" ;
                $out .= " <br>";
                $out .= '<div class="date">' . get_field('event_date') . "</div>" . "<br>";
                $out .= '<div class="time">' . get_field('event_time') . "</div>" ;
                $out .= get_field('buy_ticket_button') . "<br>";
                $out .= "</div>";

                }


            }
           return $out;

}
add_shortcode( 'todaysevent', 'custom_shortcode' );
```

Comment: There should be two slashes in the opening comment. e.g. // Also, remove the single quotes around `'$date'` in the `$args` array. The syntax otherwise seems fine. Would you please explain 'doesn't work fully'? What are you expecting to happen? What *does* happen?

Comment: Thanks, there is two slashes in the opening comment (I pasted it without accidentally).
I'm trying to get 'events' that are happening today and display them with this shortcode. So far, it will display the first event I made (even though I've deleted it) if I remove the date part. With the date part it shows nothing. 

Without the date part or $the_query->the_post(); it shows the current events in an infinite loop.

Comment: I'd add a call to [`wp_reset_postdata()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) before the closing brace of the `if` statement. From there, divide and conquer. Debug the value of `$date`. Is it in the same format as what's saved in the custom fields? BTW, you don't need `endif` or `endwhile` because the `if` and `while` loops are using regular `{}` brackets, and not the alternate `if :` `endif;` & `while :` `endwhile;` syntax.

Comment: You can write it like this: `while( true ): endwhile;` or like this: `while( true ) { }`, you've done the latter, and so you don't need to put `endwhile;` anywhere, just look at the matching braces

Comment: Your `src` attribute in the `img` tag is missing quotes around the value.

Comment: Thanks guys, that clears up much confusion. I tested this with only post type in the $args array and it still returns an old post that I deleted. I think I understand how to debug the time when it starts showing current posts but any idea why it's showing an old post I deleted ?

Comment: It appears I refer to the custom post type as events here but when I switched it to event (singular) it worked.. Now for time debugging. Thanks a million @DaveRomsey and Tom and Milo for the help

Comment: Happy to help! Please post your solution as an answer and then stop by in a couple of days. This will close out the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I spent like 5 hours trying to figure out why my proper-looking code wasn't giving me the behavior I wanted. Thanks to the fine commentators I was able to get current posts to display without the event_date specified but wasn't able to fetch posts by date.

I started thinking outside of the box and learned that it was showing 'todays' events but the timezone of the server was in a different country so it was tomorrow's events for me. I specified the default timezone and it works perfectly!

### Here's the shortcode I made to fetch my custom post type 'event' according to which ones have the custom field 'event_date' value of todays date.

```
// Add Shortcode
function custom_shortcode() {

date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");

// find todays date
$today = date("Ymd");


  // args
    $args = array(
        'post_type'     => 'event',
        'meta_key'      => 'event_date',
        'meta_value'    => $today
    );



    // query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );


            // The Loop
            if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

                $out .= '<ul>';
                while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                    $the_query->the_post();
                    $out .= "<div>";
                    $out .= get_field('event_name') . "<br>"; 
                    $out .='<img class="myimage" style="max-width:180px;" src="'. get_field('event_image') . '">' ;
                    $out .= " <br>";
                    $out .= '<div class="date">' . get_field('event_date') . "</div>" . "<br>";
                    $out .= '<div class="time">' . get_field('event_time') . "</div>" ;
                    $out .= get_field('buy_ticket_button') . "<br>";
                    $out .= "</div>";

                }

            wp_reset_postdata();
            }

           return $out;

}
add_shortcode( 'todaysevent', 'custom_shortcode' );
```